# Nested collections in VBA classes causing performance issues

Tags: vba, excel

I have run into a performance issue with VBA that may be related to how I built my OO model, but is manifested with slow performance using collections.

```
Class1:
 -Property1
 -Collection of Class2
 +GetClass2ByClass3Property1(Class3Property1)

Class2:
 -Property1
 -Property2
 -Collection of Class3

Class3:
 -Property1
 -Property2
```

First, I populate Class1,Class2, but I only populate Class3 Key - not the value.  Then I have to go back and populate the value, which results in a function in class1 like this:

```
For i=1 to Class1Collection.Count
 For j=1 to Class1Collection(i).Count
   If (Class1Collection.Item(i).Item(j) = myComparisonValue) Then
       Set myReturnValue = Class1Collection.Item(i).Item(j)
       Exit For
    End If
  Next j
Next i
```

The performance of this nested loop is awful.

Do I need to replace all the collections with arrays?  If so, any advice on how to do that least invasively.

Comment: Might help to mention what order of magnitude you're dealing with (how many i and j ?)  And what is Class3 Key?

Comment: About 300 i's and 6000 js: but let me clarify my problem a bit more.  I have the key of the collection in class2, but in order to put it in the right "place", I need to find the corresponding spot in the collection of Class2s...the real issue is the only way to find that key is to loop through every possible collection of class2s until I get match on the key that I do have...so I was able to eliminate one of the loops and instead do a key lookup, which improved performance, but it is still far below what is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is likely the comparison of

```
Class1Collection.Item(i).Item(j) = myComparisonValue
```

There are a couple of ways to optimize a string comparison. The least expensive way to do it without completely restructuring your Object Model is to do something like this:

```
Dim myComparisonValue As Long
myComparisonValue = Len(myComparisonValue)
For i = 1 To Class1Collection.Count
    For j = 1 To Class1Collection(i).Count
        If Len(Class1Collection.Item(i).Item(j)) = myComparisonValue Then
            If (Class1Collection.Item(i).Item(j) = myComparisonValue) Then
                Set myReturnValue = Class1Collection.Item(i).Item(j)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

The reason this is (often) faster is because string comparisons are *slow*. Len is just a quick read of an already stored value, so it's fast.
Unfortunately this approach will not help in the event you have many same-length keys.
For that I would consider adding a numeric key to your Collection and doing the comparison based on that. The ObjPtr function is a cheap way to get a unique key.

I also notice that your Exit For is only breaking you out of the inside loop. This may be one of the rare occasions where a Goto is appropriate, as the language has no other construct for exiting multiple nested loops.
**Edit:**
**UDT Example Added**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Type ThingAMaBob
    Key As Long
    Text As String
End Type

Private Type ThingAMaBobs
    UpperBound As Long
    Items() As ThingAMaBob
End Type

Private Type ThingAMaBobsCollection
    UpperBound As Long
    Items() As ThingAMaBobs
End Type


Private Sub Test()
    Const xMax As Long = 1000&
    Const yMax As Long = 1000&
    Dim udtCol As ThingAMaBobsCollection
    Dim stTime As Long
    Dim endTime As Long
    Dim seekValue As String
    Dim seekKey As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    stTime = GetTickCount
    udtCol = CreateUDT(xMax, yMax)
    endTime = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print "Milliseconds to fill", endTime - stTime

    x = xMax \ 2&
    y = yMax \ 2&
    seekValue = udtCol.Items(x).Items(y).Text

    stTime = GetTickCount
    seekKey = SeekKeyByValue(udtCol, seekValue, True)
    endTime = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print "Milliseconds to get key by value", endTime - stTime

    stTime = GetTickCount
    seekValue = SeekValueByKey(udtCol, seekKey)
    endTime = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print "Milliseconds to get value by key", endTime - stTime

End Sub

Private Function CreateUDT(ByVal xMax As Long, ByVal yMax As Long) As ThingAMaBobsCollection
    Dim rtnVal As ThingAMaBobsCollection
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    xMax = xMax - 1&
    yMax = yMax - 1&
    With rtnVal
        .UpperBound = xMax
        ReDim .Items(.UpperBound)
        For x = 0& To xMax
            With .Items(x)
                .UpperBound = yMax
                ReDim .Items(.UpperBound)
                For y = 0& To yMax
                    .Items(y).Text = RandomString(RndBetween(8&, 16&))
                    .Items(y).Key = StrPtr(.Items(y).Text)
                Next
            End With
        Next
    End With
    CreateUDT = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function SeekKeyByValue(ByRef col As ThingAMaBobsCollection, ByVal seekValue As String, ByVal compareCase As Boolean)
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim seekLen As Long
    Dim rtnVal As Long
    seekLen = Len(seekValue)
    If compareCase Then
        For x = 0& To col.UpperBound
            For y = 0& To col.Items(x).UpperBound
                If Len(col.Items(x).Items(y).Text) = seekLen Then
                    If col.Items(x).Items(y).Text = seekValue Then
                        rtnVal = col.Items(x).Items(y).Key
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Else
        seekValue = LCase$(seekValue)
        For x = 0& To col.UpperBound
            For y = 0& To col.Items(x).UpperBound
                If Len(col.Items(x).Items(y).Text) = seekLen Then
                    If LCase$(col.Items(x).Items(y).Text) = seekValue Then
                        rtnVal = col.Items(x).Items(y).Key
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
    SeekKeyByValue = seekLen
End Function

Private Function SeekValueByKey(ByRef col As ThingAMaBobsCollection, ByVal seekKey As Long) As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim rtnVal As String
    For x = 0& To col.UpperBound
        For y = 0& To col.Items(x).UpperBound
            If col.Items(x).Items(y).Key = seekKey Then
                rtnVal = col.Items(x).Items(y).Key
            End If
        Next
    Next
    SeekValueByKey = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function RandomString(ByVal Length As Long, Optional ByVal charset As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789~!@#$%^&*()_+`-={}|:""<>?[]\;',./") As String
    Dim chars() As Byte, value() As Byte, chrUprBnd As Long, i As Long
    If Length > 0& Then
        Randomize
        chars = charset
        chrUprBnd = Len(charset) - 1&
        Length = (Length * 2&) - 1&
        ReDim value(Length) As Byte
        For i = 0& To Length Step 2&
            value(i) = chars(CLng(chrUprBnd * Rnd) * 2&)
        Next
    End If
    RandomString = value
End Function

Private Function RndBetween(ByVal UpperBound As Long, ByVal lowerbound As Long) As Long
    VBA.Math.Randomize
    RndBetween = Int((UpperBound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
End Function
```

Comment: I generally agree with the thinking here, but my performance is not related to the string comparison, it is more related to the number of times I have to run these nested loops.  I say this, because to test I actually changed my keys to integers which should be the most ideal, and while the performance improved, it was still pretty bad.  Also, the exit for comment is accurate, but I was able to remove one of the nested loops (by using a key lookup instead) so that is no longer an issue.

Comment: FYI longs are slightly more ideal than Integers and LongPtrs are optimum:) But that is unlikely to matter:) I hate to break an object model, so the next thing I'd try is to load the keys and the values into a two-d array and wrap them with the class. Also arrays of UDTs are pretty fast and will somewhat preserve your data structure.

Comment: I included an example of a UDT hooked to a test harness. Once it is loaded with values, you can seek by key or by value for very quickly. It might be worth a try.

Comment: I'd be interested in your thoughts on what the optimum object model would be...but that would probably be a bit more complex then a SO answer.  IMO, your answer on arrays is the correct one.  Such a shame that collections perform so slowly.

Comment: It's important to remember VBA doesn't compile like C. It compiles down to PCode (think CIL) and is executed by DLLs. When you optimize using primitives there is less abstraction for it to unravel. (Current) VBA is derived from VB6. Most of what you find about optimizing VB6 and before will work for VBA. There is a ton of really good info here: http://www.aivosto.com/resources.html  Personally I tend to use the Classic OOP ways unless, like you I need to optimize, then I go to primitives behind the scenes and wrap them in classes for convenience. Only optimize when you need too.